# Open Local Internet explorer from Java Client Server Application

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, browser, client-server

I have a client server application running on one machine(server machine).
I open the application in my local machine by opening one browser(any) and typing the url of the application. Say the url is *http://serverMachineName:8080/applicationContextPath/index.jsp*.

Then there is button in the screen. When I click the button it should open the IE browoser in my local system. 
By Configuring Protocol Handler we might achieve this, but I didnt try this as we dont have that extent of access. Only way we can achieve this through is coding something.
Using ProcessCommander or RunTime class I tried to do, but failed as that runs only on host machine that is, the server machine in this case, not my local one.
Java script also might do.

Comment: So why are they not opening up the link in IE to start?

Comment: You can look into Registering an Application to a URI Scheme, but seems weird you need it to be in IE.

Comment: Reading between the lines - this is not a good idea.  Relying on a particular browser version/extension may work in the short term but will eventually not be maintainable and/or will be a security risk.  Make the app cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @All, the client requirement is like that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it will be useful to you. I think you need something like below.I assume you can have button like below

```
<input type="button" Value="Test" onClick="RunBatch();"
```

your java script that calls batch script and uses ActiveXObject (which will throw security risks for first time access.You have to accept it).

```
function RunBatch(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"C:/test.bat"';
    shell.run(path,1,false);
}
```

And in batch file test.bat you can have some thing like to open google.com in the internet explorer

```
start iexplore https://google.com
```

this will work only in IE browser as ActiveXObject is used